# React.js Bootstrap Accordion change background color when clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

My question is how can I change accordion background color when it's active in react bootstrap? Thank you!

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <Accordion>
           <Card>
            <Card.Header>
              <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
              All movies
              </Accordion.Toggle>
            </Card.Header>
            [....]
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do it the CSS way: Find what class is added by bootstrap when the accordion item is open, and style the element using plain CSS. Another way to do it using React, would be to save the active item in state and conditionally add a `style` prop to reflect the same.

Comment: @Dane Ok i have added a css class .selected but how do i save the state? Thanks btw :)

Answer (score 2):

For react-bootstrap 5, just override CSS:

```
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed) {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #29008a;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 13%);
}
```

Change color, background-color to your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to apply it to the `Card.Header` since it is configured to occupy  the entire width of the accordion. You can leverage `eventKey` to track the active accordion item which you can store in a state

```
state = {
  activeEventKey: "0"
};

activeColor = "#dddddd";

<Card.Header
  {...(this.state.activeEventKey === "0" && {
    style: { backgroundColor: this.activeColor }
  })}
>
  <Accordion.Toggle
    as={Button}
    variant="link"
    eventKey="0"
    onClick={() => this.setState({ activeEventKey: "0" })}
  >
    Click me!
  </Accordion.Toggle>
</Card.Header>
```

[image: Edit distracted-paper-tded5]

Example accordion is taken from: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

You will have to keep track of which accordion key is open by using [useState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook so you can dynamically set it. After that, you will have to check the current opened key against each card and if it matched the key of the card, you will change the style dynamically by setting `backgroundColor`. A working example would be:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import { Accordion, Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

function App() {
  const [currentActiveKey, setCurrentActiveKey] = useState(null);

  const toggleActiveKey = (key) => {
    setCurrentActiveKey(currentActiveKey === key ? null : key);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Accordion>
        <Card
          style={currentActiveKey === "0" ? { backgroundColor: "red" } : null}
        >
          <Card.Header>
            <Accordion.Toggle
              onClick={() => {
                toggleActiveKey("0");
              }}
              variant="link"
              eventKey="0"
            >
              All Movies
            </Accordion.Toggle>
          </Card.Header>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
            <div className="panel-body">Body content for panel 1</div>
          </Accordion.Collapse>
        </Card>

        <Card
          style={currentActiveKey === "1" ? { backgroundColor: "red" } : null}
        >
          <Card.Header>
            <Accordion.Toggle
              onClick={() => {
                toggleActiveKey("1");
              }}
              variant="link"
              eventKey="1"
            >
              All Movies 2
            </Accordion.Toggle>
          </Card.Header>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="1">
            <div className="panel-body">Body content for panel 2</div>
          </Accordion.Collapse>
        </Card>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank u, but i have more than one Accordion